# I can not access to webmin via squid proxy

Tags: squid, webmin

I can not access to webmin via squid proxy.

I have squid proxy and webmin set up already.

I have hostname like following.

```
・squid proxy hostname
dev-proxy.example

・webmin hostname
dev-proxy.example:10000
```

I addedd following to squid.conf.

```
# Allow webmin
acl webmin_port port 10000
acl webmin url_regex "/etc/squid/webmin.acl"
http_access allow CONNECT webmin_port localnet
http_access allow CONNECT webmin_port localhost
```

/etc/squid/webmin.acl has following URL.

```
https://dev-proxy.example
```

I can access to webmin without squid proxy.

However, I can not access to webmin if squid proxy is set.

Do you have any suggestion for this?

My environment is as following.

```
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 
SQUID Version 3.5.27
webmin version 1.941
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it myself.
I added following.

```
acl SSL_ports port 10000
```